# Can I get information about an SQL SELECT query (such as the tables it accesses) using C#?

Tags: c#, testing, sql, parsing

The c# application I'm working with executes many T-SQL SELECT queries that are stored as strings in a database.

These queries almost all involve selecting data from and joining with several tables from within the database.

Certain combinations should not be permitted, e.g. column 1 from table X should not be returned if table Y is joined on table X. A simpler example might be "Never include data from table Z"

There are many such rules and currently it is down to the author of the SQL to check that the data returned does not violate any of these rules.

I cannot edit the database in any way.

What options are there for me to determine whether a specific query violates one of these rules?

Is it possible to determine what tables/columns are accessed in a query?

I would need the solution to be reliable, I have considered parsing the SQL e.g. by using a Regex but I think this falls somewhat short of the "reliable" requirement.

Comment: `I cannot edit the database in any way.` that's _really_ unfortunate, the database is where you'd typically implement permissions like this. I'm very interested in your requirements, sounds like a weird solution. Out of curiosity, what is it all about?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589096/parsing-sql-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: `Certain combinations should not be permitted, e.g. column 1 from table X should not be returned if table Y is joined on table X. A simpler example might be "Never include data from table Z"` -- Why aren't these combinations coded into the database as constraints and triggers?  Or, a better question, why are these combinations not allowed?

Comment: Parse SQL is a little past regex

Comment: Rather then let the user type up the SQL string why not offer them a query builder that knows these rules?

Comment: This tool may help (if it can be called form code): [http://www.sqlparser.com/] You may talk to the author(s) to help.  Also, if you are using SQL Server, see this: https://codetype.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/net-sql-parsing-using-the-tsqlparser-library/

Comment: I wonder if you can get the explain plan of the TSQL before its execution. Does SQL server allow you get the Explain Plan of T-SQL?

Comment: You can use the information schema to get details on the database if you have permission.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql

Comment: Can you explain why these limitations need to be applied in the first place? It feels like an XY problem. It seems inefficient (from a coding perspective) to want to parse and inspect every SQL query, because it's so easy to go around  your rules. E.g. suppose you do hide column 1 from table X when it is joined to table Y. What's stopping them from launching a second query that retrieves table X (with column 1) and join that to their initial result? A clever querier can get around your rules. This simply causes them to launch _more_ queries to find and piece together all hidden fragments.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse T-SQL specifically, you may want to consider using Microsoft's SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) library: [SQL Server Management Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide)

Relevant namespace: [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx)